# Associate an element placed out of tab with tab items

Tags: jquery

I have a tab script that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmqeh/8/

With click on ".tab" items, ul.tab li items has class "actives". But with click on

```
<a class="bdn" href="#tab2">Go to Tab 2</a>
```

`<a class="bdn">` couldnt add  `class="actives` to tab items. How can I do this with scroll to

```
<div class="tab_content chart" id="tab2">
    this is the content of tab2
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lot easier if you just trigger the click event on the tab you want to activate:

```
$(".bdn").click(function(e) {
    var $tabs = $('ul.tab');
    $tabs.find('a[href="#tab2"]').click();
    $(window).scrollTop($tabs.offset().top);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Your fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fmqeh/11/

Comment: Triggering the click should automatically scroll there too.

Comment: Do you mean '$('ul.tab a[href="#tab2"]').trigger('click');' ?

Comment: I mean that the above code I posted should automatically take care of that. It works in the jsfiddle, just add a dummy element to push your `Go to Tab 2` link down far enough to make the window scroll, and click it. It should automatically scroll up to your tabs.

Comment: Hmm... maybe not. Either way, a simple one liner should take care of that: `$(window).scrollTop($('ul.tab').offset().top);`. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fmqeh/10/ The link is on the bottom if you scroll down.

Comment: @DarthJDG, you are my angel.. Thanks ...jasmine

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector should be:

```
 $("ul.tab li:nth-child(2)").addClass("actives");
```